# knn implementation in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, knn

I am trying to implement the `knnclassify` function on my own.

I have two matrices, `train` (45x644) and `test` (5x644) and I am trying to implement knn using euclidean to find the class of test data. 
I have found the the distance between the two and sorted them. 
I am at a loss to know what to do after this. I need to return the `k` data points which are close to my test data, is this right? If yes, how do I do that? I do not want to use the matlab function `knnclassify()`.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Use the above duplicate, but you'll have to modify it to accommodate for multiple test points. A simple loop should suffice.

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you for your reply. I used  dist = pdist2(train, test, 'euclidean') to find the distance. Is that right? I tried reading about ind, but i am not really clear. Can you please explain in short what is really does?

Comment: I tried using that piece of code. I want the value ind_closest. But this value and the value that i get when i do knnclassify(test,train,group) are different. I am confused. Please help

Comment: @zeeMonkeez: I calculated the distance and have a matrix of 5x45 which later I sorted and followed the steps given in the link that rayryeng provided

Comment: Got the answer. Had to group it according to the labels. Thank you @rayryeng and zeeMonkeez